# Como identificar qual formulário alterou a propriedade de um componente?

Tags: delphi

É possível eu identificar qual formulário alterou a propriedade de um determinado componente?

Por exemplos, tenho um `Data Module` com uma `ZTable` que é acessada por vários `forms` nos eventos `onClose` desses `forms`, precisaria verificar se a minha `zTable` foi aberta no próprio `form`. Se foi, eu fecho a `zTable`, se não foi, eu não fecho.

Comment: Para mim não está muito claro o que você está dizendo. Poderia colocar mais informações. Não sei se isso resolve seu problema, mas é uma boa prática fechar o query quando não for mais usar.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você tem um objeto compartilhado entre  vários forms e quer saber quem originalmente abriu esse objeto para fechá-lo. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Isso mesmo... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A melhor forma de fazer isso (para mim que não sei se há um padrão existente) é criar um `Helper` para o objeto zTable.

Um helper é um auxiliador de classes do Delphi que você pode usar para adicionar mais funcionalidades em uma classe, sem necessariamente alterar sua estrutura, nem fazer uma classe derivada desta. Ou seja, você vai poder continuar usando o componente diretamente da palheta de componentes do Delphi.

```delphi
TTableHelper = class helper for TzTable
public
  function OpenFromForm: boolean;
  function CloseFromForm: boolean;
  IsFormOpened: boolean;
  IsFormClosed: boolean;
end;

function TTableHelper.CloseFromForm: boolean;
begin
  try
    Self.Active := False;
    Result := True;
    ISFormClosed := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function TTableHelper.OpenFromForm: boolean;
begin
  try
    Self.Active := True;
    Result := True;
    ISFormOpened := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Faça o seguinte:

1. Crie uma nova `Unit`;
2. Coloque esta Unit na clausula `uses` de cada `Form` e do `Data Module` que usar;
3. Ao abrir a tabela pelo formulário, use  `table.OpenFromForm`;
4. Ao fechar a tabela pelo formulário, use `table.CloseFromForm`;

No `Data Module` use:

```delphi
if table.IsFormOpened then
begin
  table.isFormOpened := False;
  table.Close;
end;
```

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo que eu precisava... só não entendi uma coisa, onde eu insiro esse código no Data Module?

Comment: Coloque na Unit da cláusula 1 que você vai criar